# Easiest way to change function signature of a function that is used many times?

Tags: typescript, unix, visual-studio-code

I'm looking for recommendations on any tools I may be able to use to accomplish this.

I want to change this class' constructor as follows

```
class Arc{
    center: Point;
    radius: number;
    sweep: Sweep;

    // from this
    constructor(center: Point, radius: number, startAngle: number, sweepAngle: number) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.sweep = new Sweep(startAngle, sweepAngle);
    }

    // to this
    constructor(center: Point, radius: number, sweep: Sweep) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.sweep = sweep;
    }
}
```

Rather than having Arc know about Sweep's constructor, I would like to use dependency injection here. It makes testing easier, and I think it makes more sense because I'm also using the Factory pattern, I have a few factories that call the constructor.

The issue with this change is that I have over 200 references to the constructor across my code base. They're almost all in tests that I wrote poorly.

Is there anyway I can change all of these calls to the constructor while maintaining the properties? I'm using VSCode as my IDE and I'm comfortable with some unix commands.

Something like this:

```
new Arc(new Point(0, 0), 1, 0, Math.PI);
// I want to carry through 0 and Math.PI to the Sweep constructor.
new Arc(new Point(0, 0), 1, new Sweep(0, Math.PI));
```

Comment: write a simple regex that captures the last 2 arguments (can they be expressions or function calls then it is more difficult) and replace with a `Sweep` construction

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm has some Typescript refactorings. I don't have any specific experience with it, but I'd *try* this:

1. Do a global search and replace to remove the space, so that `new Arc(new Point(0, 0), 1, 0, Math.PI);` becomes `newArc(new Point(0, 0), 1, 0, Math.PI);`
2. Introduce a global function, `newArc` that calls the preferred constructor instead.
3. Use the "inline method" refactoring to remove `newArc` which will (hopefully) replace all of the callers with the new code.

Make sure you've got some backups (or source control) and see how you get on.